# Invoice table design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, invoice

I am creating an invoice table for the customers. Sometime they will have to send me the commission fees or sometime I send them fees (account balance). How to design a invoice table in this situation?

I have came up with this solution, im not sure if this is correct or what is the alternative way?

```
tbl_invoice
- invoice_id (PK)
- order_id (FK)
- invoice_date
- amount (copy the price from tbl_order.total table)
- status (Invoice Sent, Cancelled, Amount Received, Amount Sent)


tbl_Payments
 - invoice_id (FK)
 - amount_received (recieved commission fees from customer)
 - amount_sent (sent fees to customer)
 - date_received
 - date_sent
```

if the tbl_invoice.amount is -30.00 that mean customer will send me the fees.

if the tbl_invoice.amount is 30.00 then I will send the customer the fees.

Do I need tbl_invoice.amount field?

If you could redesign my tables how it should be that be great.

Comment: It seems a bit inconsistent to me that you're using only one amount field in one table and two fields in the other table.  Why not use  single amount field for tbl_Payments? If it's negative, then you got the fees.  If it's positive then you sent the fees?

Comment: @Seun, When I got the fees, I might forget to enter the - (negative). As on the backend I could enter the dropdown (Amount received, Amount Sent) and it will be updated to particular field.

Comment: exact duplicate of [Invoice table: Send fees and Receive Fees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329054/invoice-table-send-fees-and-receive-fees)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. Normalize invoice status to be its own lookup table, then put a Status ID in the invoice table rather than 'Sent', 'Cancelled', etc.
2. Definitely keep invoice amount. This might have to be different from the price value in tbl_order.total if you ever need to take into account discounts. In any case, numerical data is cheap to store and will be faster to query if you dont have to do any joins.
3. Give the Payments table its own ID column and make it the PK.
4. The rest looks ok. There is a case for having two tables, one for payments outgoing, and another for payments incoming. If you really only need to keep the amount and date information, then I dont think you need to make it any more complicated.

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Thanks for answer Christ. Just a quick question. Let say invoice has been generated and the invoice amount is -120.00 (minus) then I printed the invoice and change the status to 2 (Invoice Sent). When I received fees from the customer.. then I enter the amount in the tbl_Payments.amount_received and then finally change the invoice status to completed (tbl_invoice.status = 1) .. Is this correct way to do it?

Comment: Also can you think of any more fields that can be added in the tbl_Payments and tbl_invoice.. maybe like tracking? how can that be done.

Comment: Hi yes - changing the state as you describe is fine. As you mentioned, it is 'best practice' to keep an audit trail which will allow you to see all changes of state for a particular invoice. Audit tables are usually quite generic, you could have one with the columns {Event Id, Event Type, Event Description, Invoice Id, DateTime} where an example row might be {1, '200', 'Invoice Marked As Paid', 23235532, '13/06/2011 : 14:00'}

Comment: Audit tables is a good idea. If I understand correctly, if I make any changes in the invoice then it will add into audit table?  Let there is a mistake in the tbl_order.total but the invoice has already been generated.. If I make the changes in  tbl_order.total and then it should update tbl_invoice.amount automatically via PHP/SQL?

Comment: No, you'll have to update the Audit table either manually (in code) or through the use of a Trigger on the invoive or payment tables. Please dont forget to mark my answer as correct if it is helpful! thanks.

Comment: You are helpful and marked your answer :) Why update update the Audit table? But not inserting a new row in the Audit table when the invoice change.. so I will get a list of changes, for example: {SELECT * FROM audit_invoice where Invoice Id = '123'} also if I make a change in the tbl_order.total then  invoice.amount should be updated too?

Comment: My bad - by 'update' I do mean 'insert'. Once in the Audit table, rows should not be changed. When any data (such as state of an invoice or payment) is changed in the other tables, a new row is added to the audit table, so as you say, you can see the whole history of that invoice. Hope this clears it up!

Answer (score 0):

You should be tracking:

- amount_due
- amount_sent
- amount_received

All three are important. And in the payments, also track the fee_paid.

Lastly, it's usually better to use T-ledger accounting (i.e. debit/credit) for this kind of stuff. It makes things much cleaner if you ever need to worry about discounts, coupons, refunds, chargebacks, etc.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by tracking? Could you provide example table of that please? amount_due is tbl_invoice.amount  ... What is fee_paid? Isn't that is amount_sent or amount_received in the tbl_Payments. If you could redesign my tables, that be great thanks

Comment: What I'm meaning is that as things stand, your dedsign is not capable processing the likes of: i want a partial refund/I got $5 off of my next invoice as a commercial gesture/my monthly subscription was decreased by $2/etc. It also won't deal with product name changes, customer address changes, etc. Plenty to chew on...